# How to fix "Typeerror<'Request url must be str or unicode got %s: '>

Tags: python, scrapy

So i am new to scrapy and created my first spider. But i got the the type error.

This spider just **scrapes** quotes from the first page of goodreads. It's 30 quotes with tags and author name name.

```
import scrapy

class Goodreadspider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'goodreads'

    def start_requests(self):
        url = ['https://www.goodreads.com/quotes?page=1']
        yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)
    def parse(self, parse):
        for quote in response.selector.xpath("//div[@class='quote']"):
            yield{
            'text': quote.xpath("//div[@class='quoteText']/text()[1]").extract_first,
            'author': quote.xpath("//div[@class='quoteText']/child::a/text()").extract_first,
            'tags': quote.xpath("//div[@class='greyText smallText left']/a/text()").extract()
            }
```

> Typeerror<'Request url must be str or unicode, got %s:'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to remove the [] ?

`url = 'https://www.goodreads.com/quotes?page=1'`

Answer (score 0):

I think you have this error because you are trying to pass a list instead of a str or a unicode as ask by "scrapy.Request"

try this:

```
def start_requests(self):
        url = 'https://www.goodreads.com/quotes?page=1'
        yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)
```

It should work.

Comment: Thanks bro. I did that and it has solved my problem. Thank you once again.